# I keep get this error: MongoServerError: E11000

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, authentication

I'm trying to do user authentification with passport and mongodb but I keep getting an error. I tried restarting the server and looking for places to put an await function but I believe I covered all my tracks. I'm still getting the error and I have no idea why. It might be in the database itself but I am not sure because I'm new to mongodb

the error:

```
app: authRouter MongoServerError: E11000 duplicate key error collection: mernpractice.users index: email_1 dup key: { email: null }
  app: authRouter     at C:\Users\Yanki XXIV\Desktop\pluralsight\node_modules\mongodb\lib\operations\insert.js:51:33
  app: authRouter     at C:\Users\Yanki XXIV\Desktop\pluralsight\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cmap\connection_pool.js:272:25
  app: authRouter     at handleOperationResult (C:\Users\Yanki XXIV\Desktop\pluralsight\node_modules\mongodb\lib\sdam\server.js:363:9)
  app: authRouter     at MessageStream.messageHandler (C:\Users\Yanki XXIV\Desktop\pluralsight\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cmap\connection.js:479:9)
  app: authRouter     at MessageStream.emit (events.js:400:28)
  app: authRouter     at processIncomingData (C:\Users\Yanki XXIV\Desktop\pluralsight\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cmap\message_stream.js:108:16)
  app: authRouter     at MessageStream._write (C:\Users\Yanki XXIV\Desktop\pluralsight\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cmap\message_stream.js:28:9)
  app: authRouter     at writeOrBuffer (internal/streams/writable.js:358:12)
  app: authRouter     at MessageStream.Writable.write (internal/streams/writable.js:303:10)
  app: authRouter     at TLSSocket.ondata (internal/streams/readable.js:726:22) +0ms
(node:484) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'close' of undefined
    at addUser (C:\Users\Yanki XXIV\Desktop\pluralsight\src\routers\authRouter.js:29:16)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:484) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:484) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
  app: authRouter MongoServerError: E11000 duplicate key error collection: mernpractice.users index: email_1 dup key: { email: null }
  app: authRouter     at C:\Users\Yanki XXIV\Desktop\pluralsight\node_modules\mongodb\lib\operations\insert.js:51:33
  app: authRouter     at C:\Users\Yanki XXIV\Desktop\pluralsight\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cmap\connection_pool.js:272:25
  app: authRouter     at handleOperationResult (C:\Users\Yanki XXIV\Desktop\pluralsight\node_modules\mongodb\lib\sdam\server.js:363:9)
  app: authRouter     at MessageStream.messageHandler (C:\Users\Yanki XXIV\Desktop\pluralsight\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cmap\connection.js:479:9)
  app: authRouter     at MessageStream.emit (events.js:400:28)
  app: authRouter     at processIncomingData (C:\Users\Yanki XXIV\Desktop\pluralsight\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cmap\message_stream.js:108:16)
  app: authRouter     at MessageStream._write (C:\Users\Yanki XXIV\Desktop\pluralsight\node_modules\mongodb\lib\cmap\message_stream.js:28:9)
  app: authRouter     at writeOrBuffer (internal/streams/writable.js:358:12)
  app: authRouter     at MessageStream.Writable.write (internal/streams/writable.js:303:10)
  app: authRouter     at TLSSocket.ondata (internal/streams/readable.js:726:22) +9s
(node:484) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'close' of undefined
    at addUser (C:\Users\Yanki XXIV\Desktop\pluralsight\src\routers\authRouter.js:29:16)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)
(node:484) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 2)
```

auth.js

```
const express = require('express');
const debug = require('debug')('app: authRouter');
const { MongoClient } = require('mongodb');

const authRouter = express.Router();

authRouter.route('/signUp').post((req, res) => {
    const {username, password} = req.body;
    const url = 
    'mongodb+srv://Yoshi:Yumcmaster1@cluster0.atic5.mongodb.net?retryWrites=true&w=majority'
    const dbName = 'mernpractice';

    (async function addUser(){
        let client
        try {
          let client = await MongoClient.connect(url);
            
          const db = client.db(dbName);
          const user = {username, password};
          const results = await db.collection('users').insertOne(user);
          debug(results);
          req.login(results.ops[0], ()=> {
            res.redirect('/auth/profile');
          });

        } catch (error) {
          debug(error)
        }
        client.close();
    }());

});
authRouter.route('/profile').get((req, res) => {
    res.json(req.user);
})

module.exports = authRouter;
```

app.js

```
const express = require('express');
const chalk = require('chalk');
const debug = require('debug')('app');
const morgan = require('morgan');
const path = require('path');
const passport = require('passport');
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
const session = require('express-session');

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;
const app = express();
const sessionsRouter = require('./src/routers/sessionsRouter');
const adminRouter = require('./src/routers/adminRouter');
const authRouter = require('./src/routers/authRouter');

app.use(morgan('tiny'));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/public/')));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: false}));
app.use(cookieparser());
app.use(session({secret: 'globomantics'}));

require('./src/config/passport.js')(app)


app.set('views', './src/views')
app.set('view engine', 'ejs')

app.use('/sessions', sessionsRouter);
app.use('/admin', adminRouter);
app.use('/auth', authRouter);

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.render('index', { title: 'Globomantics', data: ['a','b','c'] });
});

app.listen(PORT, () => {
    debug(`listening on port ${chalk.green(PORT)}`);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

the error "E11000 duplicate key error index: ..." is due to bad data in DB, you need to cleanup your data in collection mernpractice.users as there are multiple records with email missing/null and you have unique index on the email.

you can get all missing emails using query:

```
db.users.find({
  email: {
    $exists: false
  }
})
```

or

```
db.collection.find({
  email: null
})
```

you need to clean all documents with email null or set unique email for all such documents returned by query.

Also when you insert new record you need to ensure email is available otherwise it will insert first record with null but all subsequent inserts will try to insert email as null and throw same error.

pls refer to https://www.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/e11000-duplicate-key-error-collection/14141 and https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-unique/#unique-index-and-missing-field

Comment: where exactly do I put this ? I tried putting it in the auth.js, in the authRouter.route function and it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

For me, it was because I set a field say email in a schema to unique. I created a document and set the value of the email to 'exampleemail@example.com'. The problem occurred when I tried to create/update a new document whose value of an email is the same as the above.